# In SQL how to use if statement using update table command

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update 2 columns in a table using the update command and I have to use if statement.
Table:

```
SQL> create table report(customer_no number primary key, name varchar2(10) not null, current_meter_reading number not null, previous_meter_reading number not null, category_code number not null, units_consumed number, bill_amount number(5,2), remarks varchar2(20));
```

For the bill_amount and remarks I need to use if statement, condition:

IF Category code = 1 Bill amount = Units consumed * 0.90, REMARKS = “DOMESTIC”

IF Category code = 2 Bill amount = Units consumed * 2.40, REMARKS = “COMMERCIAL”

IF Category code = 3 Bill amount = Units consumed * 0.50, REMARKS = “FARMERS”

The final output should look like this:[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRqHf.png)

Comment: What RDBMS are you **actually** using? Why did you tag this with MySQL, SQL Server and SQLite? They all have their own separate SQL dialects.

Comment: I'm using oracle

Comment: @Gyanesh Then why did you tag with all those other databases?

Comment: sorry this is the first time I'm using this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a `CASE` expression here:

```sql
UPDATE report
SET amount = CASE Category_Code WHEN 1 THEN Units_Consumed * 0.90
                                WHEN 2 THEN Units_Consumed * 2.40
                                WHEN 3 THEN Units_Consumed * 0.50 END,
    remarks = CASE Category_Code WHEN 1 THEN 'DOMESTIC'
                                 WHEN 2 THEN 'COMMERCIAL'
                                 WHEN 3 THEN 'FARMERS' END
WHERE Category_Code IN (1, 2, 3);
```

But note that if the underlying data in the table might change, you should instead consider just using a `SELECT` with the above logic as computed columns.  That is, I am suggesting to *not* do this update if you expect you might ever have to do it again at a later date.

Comment: @Gyanesh I was missing a comma in the `SET` clause.  I have fixed it; please reload your page and use the latest version.

Comment: It is working. Thank you for helping me out.